# d3 data manipulation before plotting

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot, graph, data-manipulation

Good evening everybody,

I am working for the first time on a visualization using D3. Basically I want to plot a bar chart that plots means of groups.

For example:

```
    d3.csv("sample.csv", function(d) {
    return {
        "currency"      : +d["year"],
        "month"         : +d.month,
        "spendings"     : +d.spendings
    }
})

.then(function(data) {

chart_group.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(sample.filter(function(d) { return d["currency"] === temp_curr; }))
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
```

It is easily possible to create a new object containing the dynamic data i want. Group by curreny and mean the spending.

Is it possible to replace the .data(sample) by another object I created. Somehow the plot is always empty changing it. If it is not. How can I get the mean as y value?

```
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.spendings); })
```

I tried many things including nesting and d3.mean but there are always errors messages complaining about lists instead of single values. I totally get that but don't know how to do the trick.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try .data(data.filter since data is the var name provided to the function containing your d3 code

Comment: Forgot to mention the d3 key function to "bind" a datum to a plot graphic: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/